# mongoose.model() method returning undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to find a mongoDB entry using the .findOne method, but it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')
```

I feel that this has got something to do with the .models/.model method in my schema file since I'm not receiving any compile info, i.e returning `undefined` type. I'm likely doing something wrong, so any help pointing it out would be appreciated -
Thank you

Schema file:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const banSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    reason: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    period: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'permanent'
    }
})

const name = 'Ban'
//
console.log(typeof(mongoose.models[name] || mongoose.model[name, banSchema])) // Undefined
//
module.exports = mongoose.models[name] || mongoose.model[name, banSchema]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be exporting your model like this

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Ban', banSchema);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling)

Comment: Took me a bit to figure out what the difference was - it's rounded brackets, not squared! Thank you